# How to get a list of all subdomains of a website?

Tags: google-search, blog

I'd like to, using Google Search, get a complete list of all the blog URLs that are hosted under specific domains. You know, like "[blog].wordpress.com", "[blog].blogspot.[any]" "[blog].blogs.sapo.pt", and the like.

Let's consider ".blog.sapo.pt". For `* site:blogs.sapo.pt`, I need to get rid of every result that has a `path` after the domain, that is, `-inurl:/` . But Google disconsider characters like `/`, so it's more complex.

Is there a way to search the way I need using Google? If it's possible, how to do it?

I don't want to need to resort to [a DoS-like method of "brute-checking"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132014/19314948).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate target on SO: ["_How do I get a list of all subdomains of a domain? \[closed\]_"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/131989/11107541). And another one: ["_Is it possible to find all DNS subdomains for a given domain name? \[closed\]_"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/305495/11107541).